# Lync Server - I Try Create App Monitoring users change status (offline, busy, active....)

Tags: server, lync

How to create an application? I'm trying connect to Lync Server using UCMA, SDK or how to create signal/Event Where any user change of status then the user (push method) to obtain information about the user and his status
I am a beginner in C# and Lync Server

I'm trying to help this forum Microsoft but there is no answer

Very thenx for all the help, tips sample code :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is a [UCMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984.aspx) application.

Once you have a UCMA application with a application endpoint you want to subscribe to [presence changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn465955.aspx) of the users you wish to monitor.

Microsoft even has a [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn454838.aspx) of doing just that.